# Преобразование функции JavaScript в Java

Tags: android, javascript, java

Друзья, помогите перевести функцию, написанную на языке JavaScript, на язык Java так, чтобы функция принимала как массивы так и строковые переменные.

Спасибо.

```
function str_replace ( search, replace, subject ) { 
if(!(replace instanceof Array)){
    replace=new Array(replace);
    if(search instanceof Array){
        while(search.length>replace.length){
            replace[replace.length]=replace[0];
        }
    }
}
if(!(search instanceof Array))search=new Array(search);
while(search.length>replace.length){
    replace[replace.length]="";
}
if(subject instanceof Array){
    for(k in subject){
        subject[k]=str_replace(search,replace,subject[k]);
    }
    return subject;
}
for(var k=0; k<search.length; k++){
    var i = subject.indexOf(search[k]);
    while(i>-1){
        subject = subject.replace(search[k], replace[k]);
        i = subject.indexOf(search[k],i);
    }
}
return subject;
}
```

Comment: На кой ляд это может потребоваться в java?

Answer (score 2):

А в чем собсно сложность не очень понимаю...

1) Роль `Array` в Java будет играть `ArrayList<String>`

2) Функцию замены надо декларировать как function str_replace(Object search, Object replace, Object subject );

3) Приведение типов надо проводить въяв через кастирование типа `((ArrayList<String> )search).size()` - это вместо `search.length` и т.д.

Полный код намеренно не привожу, ибо это противоречит правилам форума.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в идеале увидеть бы рабочую версию, дальнейшего понимания. В яве я слаб.

Comment: Неправда, нет никакого function в джаве) Видимо, должен был быть void.

Answer (score 1):

В Java строгая типизация, это значит, что к момент вызова этого магического метода типы всех аргументов скорее всего известны (если только их специально не потеряли в какой-то момент).

Строго говоря, сделать такой же метод в Java можно, но наличие такой задачи - признак того, что где-то в другом месте что-то неправильно написано - откуда ты получаешь данные, не зная строка это или массив? (Бывает когда сериалайзер JSON на сервере плохо написан и сериализует массив из одного элемента в просто один элемент - ух капец, сам с этим намучался)

Во-вторых, нет смысла изобретать велосипед - есть навороченная библиотека [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), а в ней класс: [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach), посмотри метод `replaceEach(...)`

Метод принимает `String[]`, осталось убедиться что когда ты его вызываешь, у тебя либо массив строк, либо массив из одной строки.